# when i used Omu.AwesomeMvc include in the project at that time i face the error?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-awesome

Assembly 'Omu.AwesomeMvc, Version=4.7.3.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9c6fbba722ea1caf' uses 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'   d:\MVC Projects\Shipping Management System\trunk\RefDll\Omu.AwesomeMvc.dll  SMS.Controls

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you're building an asp.net mvc 4 project, but you've referenced the mvc 5 version of the library, you need to reference the mvc 4 version of Omu.AwesomeMvc or build/upgrade your project to mvc5